# Почему не работает проверка на пустую сторку

Tags: javascript, while

Не могу понять почему не работает проверка на пустую строку. При вводе пробела должно снова выводиться сообщение "Введите номер квартиры", а выходит "Квартиры с таким номером с этом доме не существует". Что делать? Как исправить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Apartment finder</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        let apartNum;

        while (isNaN(apartNum) || apartNum == '') {
            apartNum = prompt('Введите номер квартиры', 1)
        }

        if (apartNum >= 1 && apartNum <= 20) {
            alert(`Квартира ${apartNum} находится в подъезде №1`)
        }
        else if (apartNum >= 21 && apartNum <= 48) {
            alert(`Квартира ${apartNum} находится в подъезде №2`)
        }
        else if (apartNum >= 49 && apartNum <= 90) {
            alert(`Квартира ${apartNum} находится в подъезде №3`)
        }
        else if (apartNum == null) {
            alert(`Вы не ввели номер квартиры`)
        }
        else {
            alert(`Квартиры с таким номером с этом доме не существует`)
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому, что пробел это не пустая строка, используйте `parseInt(apartNum)` перед проверкой, это вернет `NaN` для любого нечисла, и для пустой строки тоже и тогда вам нужна будет только проверка `isNaN(parseInt(apartNum))`

Comment: Кстати, дальнейшие сравнения с числами некорректны, т.к. apartNum всё еще строка

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, только parseInt тут и не хватало...

Comment: @Qwertiy а чем и кому тут помешал parseInt, если нужно получить число из того, что вводит пользователь?

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, `parseInt("1ove")`?

Answer (score 1):

Удалите пробелы с помощью `your_text.trim()` затем делайте проверку